# Handling cache in play framework while application is running on multiple machines

Tags: caching, playframework-2.0

I am new to play framework. My application is running on 4 machines and each instance is having its own play cache. I am storing some information in DB and it can be updated using a request. So now, when I update this info it gets updated in DB and cache of the machine from where this request is made. But later on when I make some other request which needs this info and goes to other machine it is picked from the cache of that machine, which is not updated.

How to handle this situation. How can I sync all the cache? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a distributed / shared cache, such as [Memcached](http://memcached.org/). It will sync the cache between your several instances.

The Play built-in cache is based on [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/), AFAIK, it does not provide the distributed feature.